# Remove headers from a GuzzleHTTP request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to send a request using the code snippet below:

```
$response = $client->request('POST','http://pesamoni.com/api/live/v1/transactions', [
         'form_params'   => [
         'method'        => 'acreceive',
         'apiusername'   => '1276539738zx3287',
         'mobile'        => str_replace('+', '',$this->senders_contact),
         'chanel'        => 'TIG',
         'referral'      => str_replace('+', '',$this->referer),
         'apipassword'   => 'hddjaslasdasdwe',
         'amount'        => '500',
         'reference'     => 'adasd',
         'genericmsg'    => 'test',
         'token'         => '545345345',
         'metadata'      => 'something',
         'callback'      => 'http://church.pahappa.com/'
                            ]
]);
```

I want to send this request with no headers, I have tried using:

```
$response->removeHeader('User-Agent');
```

but it is not working.
How can I remove headers from the request?

Comment: `$client->request()->withoutHeader()`

Comment: Please remove any credentials from your question.

Comment: whatever is there is not right, its wrong data. i just wanted to show the format

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Guzzle Documentation](https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#headers)

> ```
> // Will disable adding in default headers.
> $client->request('GET', '/get', ['headers' => null]);
> ```

So set `headers` to `null` in your request.